# Incorrect syntax near 'FOR'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

Following code is not working -

```
SELECT [LY-1], 
       LY = STUFF((SELECT ',' + name FROM temp1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1,      1, '' ) 
FROM temp1 
GROUP BY [LY-1];
```

As it is giving below error-

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 73
>   Parse error at line: 2, column: 36: Incorrect syntax near 'temp1'.

Does STUFF and FOR XML are not working Data warehouse ? and is there any alternative for them?

Comment: What is `Data Warehouse` mean in this context? Is this just a sql server and your submitting this through a sql client like SSMS or similar? Is this "Azure SQL Data Warehouse" ([In which case this isn't supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017))? The query *looks* right.

Comment: Is [LY-1] the literal name of a column, or are you trying to run a calculation on the 'LY' column you define in the line below?

Comment: If you are using Azure SQL Data Warehouse check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336785/aggregate-strings-in-azure-sql-data-warehouse)

Comment: string_agg() function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the equal sign is working how you want. Assuming LY is a calculated column and not a column that already exist in the table the query should be:

```
SELECT [LY-1], 
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + name FROM temp1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1,      1, '' ) AS LY
FROM temp1 
GROUP BY [LY-1];
```

For TSQL to create calculated columns you always use the logic first then give the column the name.